# Map different functions to data

Tags: python

Is there a way to make several functions map to the same data producing a list of results?

Something like

```
mapfunc([sin, cos, tan], data)
```

to produce a map object essentially mapping

```
[array(sin(data)), 
 array(cos(data)), 
 array(tan(data))]
```

?

The pythonic way is to do

```
[f(data) for f in [sin, cos, tan]]
```

But is there a map like way to do it?

EDIT: Following comments (@Dan Getz) I realize I was too loose on the output. I actually wanted to get

```
[map(sin,data),
 map(cos,data),
 map(tan,data)]
```

I guess again

```
[map(f,data) for f in [sin, cos, tan]]
```

is the right way.

Comment: `map` is to apply one function to multiple items, not vice versa. What's the actual problem, if any, with what you have?

Comment: @jonsharpe It doesn't work well for complex data. e.g. `data = [1, [2,3,4], [4,5]]` with `[f(data) for f in [len]] will result with `[3]` and not `[1,3,2]`. Other functions like `isinf` will not parse correctly the nested list at all and will result with an error.

Comment: The problem there is your data structure, not Python. Why are some elements single items and some further lists?

Comment: @Theguy You will run into those same complexities with a mapping solution. Your current approach is just about as good as it gets - you should focus on resolving your data structures into something consistent, or applying some middle function for the structure issues.

Comment: Your question in your comment above is totally different from in your question post. In your original question you would *want* the answer to be 3, but in your comment for some reason you don't. It seems you're using the word "essentially" to mean "in a significantly different way". Could you please [edit] your question to ask what you actually want to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a helper function if you want to stick with map, e.g.

```
map(lambda f: f(data), [sin, cos, tan])
```